# JQuery Onclick get value from span and add it to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery click event setup:

```
$(".clickhere").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

I also have a span with an id of `spanval`.

```
<span id="spanval">1</span>
```

finally I have a form with an `input`...

```
<input id="spanvalue" name="spanvalue" value="whatever_the_value_of_the_span_is" />
```

So, what I need to do is the following:

If class of `clickhere` is clicked then get the text in the `span` and put it in the `spanvalue`'s value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(".clickhere").click(function(){
    $('#spanvalue').val($('#spanval').text());
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Skcjn/)

Note that your's DOM elements naming is really really confusing... (`spanvalue` V.S. `spanval`)